# Unable to compile GCC, but no specific error given

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to compile gcc 4.7.1 on Mint Linux with gcc 4.7.2 and get the following output:

```
[snip]
ar rc .libs/libgmp.a assert.o compat.o errno.o [snip]
rm -fr .libs/libgmp.lax
creating libgmp.la
(cd .libs && rm -f libgmp.la && ln -s ../libgmp.la libgmp.la)
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/projects/os/linux/src/gcc-4.7.0/build/gmp'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/projects/os/linux/src/gcc-4.7.0/build/gmp'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/projects/os/linux/src/gcc-4.7.0/build/gmp'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/projects/os/linux/src/gcc-4.7.0/build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/projects/os/linux/src/gcc-4.7.0/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't even know where to start looking since I don't get a descriptive error! It looks like it compiles GMP successfully and then fails after that, unable to complete whatever the next step should be.

Comment: Error is probably much earlier in the scrollback.

Comment: Did you build with a `-j` flag or something?  Maybe the error is back farther in your log.

Comment: try running make like this: `make > STDOUT` and see the console output

Comment: You were right, favoretti. The error was due to an improper global variable. Not sure why it would continue compiling past this error, though!
Carl, I was using a -j flag but I'm curious why that might have been a problem? Just for my own future reference.

Comment: @user1844650, if you use `-j` and one of the 'branches' of the build errors out, other currently active branches will continue building until they complete as well.  That can mean your error is hundreds or thousands of lines farther back in the log, followed by lots of successful build messages from other branches.

Comment: What is the point of compiling GCC 4.7.1 when your distribution gives you a GCC 4.7.2? (They are nearly the same, except a few bug fixes...)

Comment: @CarlNorum is exactly right. IMHO the best way to proceed when that happens is to rerun `make` _without_ any `-j` option, so the compilation fails again and you can see the error clearly without it being masked by hundreds of lines of unrelated output.

Comment: +1 @JonathanWakely.  That's usually what I do.  You can also try sending your build's standard output and standard error into different files, or even just a single file to make searching easier.

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered in its comments above. To sum up: The error was due to an improper global *(presumably environment)* variable, much earlier in the scrollback; that because OP was using a -j flag and other currently active branches did continue building.